# How to put content on the news site?

Tags: web-development

I have a website. My time is low. If I copy the news from other sites and put the with no follow link on my site. Will my site be penalized? or Good for my site? my time is low.I want Ways To Make The Most Of my Time.
thank you. :)

Comment: "...and put the with no follow link on my site." - Can you please explain? This sounds completely backward (and black-hat)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy the news from other site you should have permission from the site to avoid copyright infringement.
Let's say you have permission then you will not be penalized as long as you have a reason to serve the same content on your website too. Here few examples:

- You have a white website with black text only, very big font to facilitate
  people with impaired vision
- you serve your website in a version for mobile when the other website
  doesn't
- you allow comments when the other website doesn't
- Your site is super fast compare to the original

So you give a reason to Google to serves your result instead of the original source to a determinate class of users (don't forget you need permission from the source)

If You re-edit will be OK but this will be time consuming, in this case also you will not be penalized.

Penalized: is not that you will be banned, is only that between the original and the copy Google will choose the original to be served as result in search. If you will go on and on just copying without "reason" (so not only for a quick start) Google will consider your website a low quality website and you will drop to the far end of search result. Anyway you will not be consider a spam website.

So the **way to make the most** is to choose a way to present non original content in a more usable way, with permission from the source of course. There are some news agency that for low fee allow you to use them content.